# Getting data from mongo db like we get in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I am inserting some value into mongodb in this way.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("paramDescMapper");
    String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String value = "{\"param0\":\"Car Make\",\"param1\":\"Car Model\",\"param2\":\"Car Variant\",\"param3\":\"Car Year\",\"param4\":\"Car Number\"}";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);

    // create a document to store key and value
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("apiKey", key);
    document.put("apiParamDesc", jsonObject.toString());
    table.insert(document);
```

It is inserting data in this way.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "534251125f1ab7ec747298cd"} , "apiKey" : "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6" , "apiParamDesc" : "{\"param0\":\"Car Make\",\"param1\":\"Car Model\",\"param2\":\"Car Variant\",\"param3\":\"Car Year\",\"param4\":\"Car Number\"}"}
```

Now i want to get apiParamDesc value using apiKey. Like how we get data in mysql.

> Select apiParamDesc where apiKey =
>   '1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6';

I googled a lot but could not found anything. This is how i am trying to get this apiParamDesc

```
    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("apiKey", "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6");
    DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

But this is giving me entire row. I want only apiParamDesc in a String.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want only apiParamDesc in a String.

You cannot however, you can get a document (object) returned with only the `apiParamDesc` as its single field (my Java is rusty):

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("apiKey", "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6");

BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.put("apiParamDesc", 1);
fields.put("_id", 0);

DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery, fields);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with aggregation framework. Below is the example which can resolve your issue:

```
// create our pipeline operations, first with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("apiKey", "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6"));

// build the $projection operation
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("apiParamDesc", 1);
fields.put("_id", 0);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

 // run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( match, project);
```

You can also make use of only `db.coll.find(< criteria >, < projection >);`

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("apiKey", "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6"), new BasicDBObject("apiParamDesc", 1).append("_id", 0));

//Which is equivalent to a follwoing query 
//'db.coll.find({"apiKey": "1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6"}, {"apiParamDesc": 1,"_id": 0});'

cursor = coll.find(query);
```

---

One more thing to update you on `"I want only apiParamDesc in a String."`, is if you are storing string like

> "apiParamDesc" : "{\"param0\":\"Car Make\",\"param1\":\"Car Model\",\"param2\":\"Car Variant\",\"param3\":\"Car Year\",\"param4\":\"Car Number\"}

You cannot query on those sub level fields like `param0`, `param1` ...
You data should look like :

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"534251125f1ab7ec747298cd"
   },
   "apiKey":"1eb9b9e3-3af1-4b25-b7ea-1f2fcb1d9af6",
   "apiParamDesc":{
      "param0":"Car Make",
      "param1":"Car Model",
      "param2":"Car Variant",
      "param3":"Car Year",
      "param4":"Car Number"
   }
}
```

Comment: I am storing it a encoded json string so later i will parse this string using json api.Well thank you so much. It is working now :)